# Getting the Content-Type of a servlet reponse on a Filter

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to catch and log the "Content-Type" of a response on a Filter servlet. I've tried applying the approach decribed [here.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200301.mbox/%3C20030117181949.O48865-100000@icarus.apache.org%3E) Yet I still get Content-Type null. How to get the Content-type of a servlet response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set response's content type?

```
response.setContentType("xml");
```

then you can use getContentType() on response object, until then you will get null.

Answer (score 0):

**getContentType()** of **ServletResponse** may help you. It will return the content type of your response in a String format.

Comment: @xybrek as mashit said it will always return null, unless you set the content type to it.See this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html for more information.

Comment: What do you mean set it? Its a Filter so I am expecting that the response will have its "Content-type", a filter to for GET something from other site. I am mistaken?

Comment: Anyway, you mean I cannot get a "Content-Type" in a Filter servlet?

Comment: I am not sure but please have a look at http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/software/contenttypefilter/